# C# Triggering event from new task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I wanted to  test if I can trigger an event using method working in a new task.

when I do this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            subscriber f = new subscriber();
        }

    }


    class subscriber
    {
        publisher x;
        public subscriber()
        {
            x = new publisher();
            x.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;
            x.method2();
        }

        static void c_ThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The threshold was reached.");
        }
    }



    class publisher
    {
        public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;


        public publisher()
        {
       
        }

        public void method1()
        {
            OnThresholdReached(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void method2()
        {
            Task.Run(() => method1());

        }


        protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

    }
}
```

The output is nothing!

However, when I do this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            subscriber f = new subscriber();
        }

    }


    class subscriber
    {
        publisher x;
        public subscriber()
        {
            x = new publisher();
            x.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;
            x.method2();
        }

        static void c_ThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The threshold was reached.");
        }
    }



    class publisher
    {
        public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;


        public publisher()
        {
       
        }

        public void method1()
        {
            OnThresholdReached(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void method2()
        {
            //Here is the change
            method1();
            Task.Run(() => method1());

        }


        protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

    }
}
```

the output is this:

```
The threshold was reached
The threshold was reached
```

this is strange!
I could not understand why it prints twice.

However, I excepted it will not work with method1 is running in new task, because it will not be working in the same thread

could someone explain why?
and is there a way to communicate a concurrent method with the parent thread?

thanks in advance

Comment: The first code prints nothing because the `Main` method ends before the execution of `method1`, and that makes the console application to close before printing the message.

Comment: Add `Console.ReadKey();` in `Main` to have the console wait for an input.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, your code finishes before the task will run and pring anything. You should modify your code in async manner to await the task to finish

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            subscriber f = new subscriber();
            await f.Test();
        }

    }


    class subscriber
    {
        publisher x;
        public subscriber()
        {
            x = new publisher();
            x.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;
        }
        
        public async Task Test()
        {
            await x.method2();
        }

        static void c_ThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The threshold was reached.");
        }
    }


    class publisher
    {
        public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;


        public publisher()
        {
       
        }

        public void method1()
        {
            OnThresholdReached(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public async Task method2()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => method1());
        }


        protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

    }
}
```

As for your second snippet, that looks like the Task has time to run and pring while the main thread printing inside `method1`. Some times it will pring twice (if have enaught of time) or will print once (if Console.Write in main thread will finish before the task will run).

**Additional note**: please be aware that your event handler will be called not in main thread, but in the thread in which task is executed (typically, this will be a thread from a thread pool)

Answer (score 0):

When you call Task.Run(...), the action inside Run() will be started in new thread.

In your first case you start the new thread with `Task.Run()`, but the program finishes and exits before it executes that the new thread.
You can prevent the main thread from terminating by adding `Console.Read()` at the end of `Main()`. This way you can wait for the second thread to finish.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        subscriber f = new subscriber();
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

In your second case you will get two messages because of this:

```
public void method2()
{
    method1();
    Task.Run(() => method1());
}
```

This time since you are directly calling `method1()` you will for sure write the message once in the console. Since printing on the console (any IO in general) is relatively slow, the second thread (created by `Task.Run()`) will have time to execute, and print the message second time.

Another solution is to create the thread manually

```
public void method2()
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() => method1());
    t1.IsBackground = false;
    t1.Start();
}
```

The program will not exit until all foreground threads have finished. So when you set `IsBackground = false;`, the program will wait for that thread